# Como chamar um novo frame após conferir uma entrada de input box no Tkinter?

Tags: funções, tkinter, button, frames

Bom dia! Estou fazendo um jogo onde o usuário precisa digitar as senhas que ele descobre no decorrer do game para desbloquear novas telas. Porém, não estou conseguindo fazer com que o meu botão conferidor de senha funcione corretamente. Ele chama uma função para conferir a senha e mas eu não consigo fazer com que essa função troque de frame. Vou deixar uma parte do meu código abaixo e, se alguém puder me ajudar, eu ficaria muito grata. Esse seria o meu arquivo principal, onde a classe SampleApp é responsável por ir trocando os frames:

```
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    '''Essa classe vai iniciar o primeiro frame e, posteriormente, 
        ir chamando os outros frames
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        # Chama o frame inicial
        self.switch_frame(Comecar)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        '''Essa chasse será chamada quando algum botão for pressionado.
            Ela irá 'apagar' o frame atual e chamar o novo.
        '''
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.place(x= 0, y=0)


class Comecar(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, width = 1367, height = 703).pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self.canvas1 = tk.Canvas(self, bg = "black", width = 1367, height = 703)
        self.canvas1.place(x= 0, y= 0)

        # Botão play
        self.botao_play = tk.Button(self, width = 20, height = 2, 
                            command = lambda: master.switch_frame(senha. Senha), anchor = tk.W)
        self.botao_play.configure(background= "red", activebackground = "red", relief = tk.FLAT,
                                        bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.botao_play_window = self.canvas1.create_window(135, 262, anchor=tk.NW, window=self.botao_play)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Chama a classe que iniciará os frames.
    app = SampleApp()
    # Dá titúlo para a janela.
    app.title("teste")
    # Define o tamanho da janela
    app.geometry("1367x703")
    # Coloca tudo para rodar
    app.mainloop()
```

Já esse seria o arquivo que possui a caixa de input e o botão que confere a senha:

```
class Senha(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, width = 1367, height = 703).pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        self.canvas1 = tk.Canvas(self, bg = "blue", bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge',
                                            width = 288, height = 512)
        self.canvas1.place(x= 542, y=98)
        
        # Caixa de input
        self.entry1 = tk.Entry (self, font=('Helvetica'), background = "white",
                                border=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas1.create_window(143, 264, window=self.entry1, width = 230, height = 20)        
        
        # Botão conferidor de senha
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self, text='CONFERIR',font=('Helvetica'), command = self.verificar, 
                                activebackground = "#a68d79", bg='#a68d79', fg='white',
                                relief = tk.FLAT, width = 10, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas1.create_window(145, 300, window=self.button2)
        
    def verificar(self):
        self.x = self.entry1.get()
        if self.x == "oi":
            print("oi")
```

O comando que eu uso nos meus outros botões para trocar os frames é:

```
command = lambda: master.switch_frame(senha. Senha)
```

Answer (score -3):

Boa tarde meu amigo,

Estou com o mesmo problema, ao chamar uma condicional 'if/else' e atrelar as entrys a uma string que desejo como login e senha não consigo chamar uma função. Mesmo digitando certo o login e senha o código pula direto para o 'else' e emite uma mensagem de erro, como se a senha e o login estivesse errados.

Resolvido, atrelei a uma função de validação com o método .get na frente das entrys de login e senha. Uma vez essa função se dando verdadeira com o 'if' o código chama uma outra função, a qual estruturei a minha nova janela.